# Problems importing Numpy OR OriginPro and Python

Tags: python, numpy, import

I am trying to build an importscript for OriginPro2018. The script works if i run it with Anaconda/Spyder 3.3.1 and Python 3.7. Everything is 64 bit and my OS is win10. If I run it from Origin (which i have to to import the data in the end) I get stuck when importing Numpy.
Since Origin does not know where my libraries are, my script starts with:

```
import sys
if not "C:\\Users\\sommer\\AppData\\Local\\Continuum\\anaconda3\\Lib\\site-packages" in sys.path:
    PkPath = "C:\\Users\\sommer\\AppData\\Local\\Continuum\\anaconda3\\Lib\\site-packages"
    sys.path.append(PkPath)
```

which tells him where to look and works as intended (based on step 4 here: http://blog.originlab.com/programming/get-access-to-external-python-packages-with-origins-embedded-python).
In the next line I import Numpy:

```
import numpy as np
```

which throws

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\sommer\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\numpy\core\__init__.py", line 16, in <module>
    from . import multiarray
ImportError: cannot import name 'multiarray'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "\\hhi.de\abteilung\PC\PC-LAS\A_Users\Studenten\Milo Sommer\OriginImport\Import_Origin.py", line 15, in <module>
    import numpy as np
  File "C:\Users\sommer\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\numpy\__init__.py", line 142, in <module>
    from . import add_newdocs
  File "C:\Users\sommer\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\numpy\add_newdocs.py", line 13, in <module>
    from numpy.lib import add_newdoc
  File "C:\Users\sommer\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    from .type_check import *
  File "C:\Users\sommer\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\type_check.py", line 11, in <module>
    import numpy.core.numeric as _nx
  File "C:\Users\sommer\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\numpy\core\__init__.py", line 26, in <module>
    raise ImportError(msg)
ImportError: 
Importing the multiarray numpy extension module failed.  Most
likely you are trying to import a failed build of numpy.
If you're working with a numpy git repo, try `git clean -xdf` (removes all
files not under version control).  Otherwise reinstall numpy.

Original error was: cannot import name 'multiarray'
```

Googling that error results in many threads about corrupted numpy installations, what i don't believe is the case since it works in Spyder.
My ideas are:

1. I use Python 3.7, Origin uses 3.5. Since the problem is numpy it seems unlikely.
2. My Anaconda Numpy version 1.15.1 is to new for Python 3.5. I tried to install a 2nd older version of Numpy, but i am having a hard time because numpy is already installed and pip thus not wanting to.

I would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to fix it myself by downloading the exact same version as OriginPro2018 uses (Python 3.5.2) and installing numpy via console.